# Exclude specific SSIS package from Azure DevOps SSIS Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, ssis, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

To set the scene - We have a DEV and Master branch (which equate to a PREPROD and PROD environment on our servers).  We create working branches off our DEV branch to develop our code, then Pull Request from working branch into DEV when we need to build then release to our PREPROD server.

We have a SSIS build pipeline with a large number of SSIS packages contained in the the project it's building.  When we need to push our changes from DEV to Master we may need to release some changes **but not all**.  We are trying to exclude updates or additions in the SSIS build so it doesn't get released to PROD, but at the moment we can't find a solution to exclude packages from the build pipeline.
We've tried the .artifactignore approach, but this doesn't seem to apply, as the we need to intervene at the build stage not the release stage.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you "build" ssis packages (in Visual Studio), all it does is copy SSIS packages to the build folder. It doesn't build anything. What does your build pipleine do? Back your real question, you seem to be asking how to cherry pick commits out of dev into master. I'm sure there is some kind of git workflow that covers that, perhaps do some reading on different git workflows.

Comment: Without knowing how the SSIS Build task was designed....the only answer i can give is.  Dunno! 
The YAML for the SSIS Build task looks pretty simple, but from the look of this is "building" the dtproj file where the packages would be reference.

steps:
- task: SSIS.ssis-devops-tools.ssis-build-task.SSISBuild@0
  displayName: 'Build SSIS_New'
  inputs:
    projectPath: 'SSIS_New/SSIS_New.dtproj'

I know how to cherry pick commits, but the process seems messy, especially if you have a large number of commits you want to push to the master branch.

Comment: the input to the build task is a project and .dtsx files. What's the output? is it a `ispac` file?

Comment: First you need a way to identify _some changes but not all_ and the obvious way would be to have a seperate branch to keep track of it